# $1,\overline{9}=2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

We want found the identity

$$\boxed{1.\overline{9}=2}$$

Let be $x=1.\overline{9}$ and multiply by $10$ it

$$10x = 10 \cdot 1.\overline{9}\iff 10 x -x=10 \cdot 1.\overline{9}-1.\overline{9}$$
$$9x=(10-1)\cdot \frac{18}{9}$$
$$9x=18 \implies \boxed{x=2}$$

Is there another proof without using series?

Comment: There can't be a real proof without series, since $1.\bar9$ is itself a series by definition.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you very much.

Comment: Equivalent to the dozens of questions about $0.\bar 9=1$ , hence a structural duplicate.